# Unable to access .net webservice in php using soap

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, soap, webservice-client

I have the following code to create a web service

```
[WebMethod]
        public string EncryptText1(string plaintext)
        {

            ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] key = textConverter.GetBytes("2a1c907916add59edffb3a4b");
            byte[] IV = textConverter.GetBytes("00000000");
            byte[] clearData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plaintext);
            byte[] cipherData = EncryptText(clearData, key, IV);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherData);
        }
    [WebMethod]
    public byte[] EncryptText(byte[] clearData, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform alg = tdes.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        cs.Close();
        byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
        return encryptedData;
    }
```

I have the following code to access the web service in php

```
<?php
$enc_wsdl = "http://172.18.0.75/EncryptionWS/EncryptionWS.asmx?wsdl";
$enc_client = new SoapClient($enc_wsdl);
$finalstring = $enc_client->EncryptText1("SomeUserName");
print_r($finalstring);
?>
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was
>   unable to process request. ---> String reference not set to an
>   instance of a String. Parameter name: s in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dotnetwebservice\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dotnetwebservice\index.php(4):
>   SoapClient->__call('EncryptText1', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dotnetwebservice\index.php(4):
>   SoapClient->EncryptText1('SomeUserName') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dotnetwebservice\index.php on line 4

Comment: Your using the `SoapClient` class wrong. Please read the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Can u please suggest me how to use this, I am using this first time

Comment: I am confused how to use soapclient

Answer (score 0):

Still I am getting the same error if I use soap, however I solved the problem using ajax call.
Below is the code:

```js
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://172.18.3.0/EncryptDecrypt/Encryptdecrypt.asmx/Encrypt",
     //url: "http://172.18.0.75/EncryptionWS/EncryptionWS.asmx/EncryptText1",
     data: JSON.stringify({'nameorpassword': 'ww'}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg)
                    {
                        alert(msg.d);
                    }
                });
```